# Error measure and learning process: sensitivity to outliers

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, robust, loss-functions

**Problem**

> **You have $N$ data points $y_1 \le \cdots \le y_N$ and wish to estimate a 'representative' value.**
>
> 1) If your algorithm is to find the hypothesis $h$ that minimizes the in-sample sum of squared deviations,
>
> $$E_{in}(h) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}{(h- y_n)^2},$$
>
> then show that your estimate will be the in sample mean,
>
> $$h_{mean} = \frac{1}{N}   \sum_{n=1}^{N}  {  y_n }.$$
>
> 2) Suppose $y_N$ is perturbed to $y_N + E$, where $E  \to \infty$.
>   So the single data point $y_N$ becomes an outlier. What happens to your two estimators $h_{mean}$ and $h_{med}$?

---

**My Answer**

I first minimized the function by taking the derivative and set it to zero :

$f(h) = E_{in}(h) = \sum_{n=1}^{N} {(h - y_n)^2}$

$ {{a}/{ay}}  ((h - y)^2)$

$2y - 2h \to 2y = 2h \to y = h$

In this case, $h$ is just a number

$h_{mean} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} {y_n}$

However, I am  failing to see how this "proof" actually makes sense regarding $h_{mean}$.
Would anyone clarify it please? Am I in the correct path?

---

And about the other question, I am really unsure but my answer is this :

Since a single point would obviously be the outlier to infinite, the $h_{mean}$ would increase; however, the $h_{med}$ would remain the same.

I find this answer too simple and I think I am missing something!

**REFERENCE**

https://work.caltech.edu/

https://work.caltech.edu/telecourse.html#lectures

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: This sounds like homework or some type of self study. That's perfectly OK, but if so please add the `self-study` tag to your question. Also, why do you expect that the proof about the _mean_ value with respect to minimizing residual sums of squares should have anything to do with the _median_? The median isn't in part (1) of the problem, just in part (2). There's a reason for that.

Comment: (+1) You seem to be thinking about this situation very well.  Have confidence!  Your conclusions are fundamentally sound.  They might be off a little bit in the details, though.  For instance, $h_{\text{med}}$ can vary as $E\to\pm\infty$.  Look at some tiny datasets to see what actually happens.

Comment: Added self study tag and added reference of text book!  I still dont get how  $h_{med}$ can vary, doesnt make sense to me.

Comment: @EdM i mistyped, sorry! Thanks for the replies guys! However im still confused :(

Comment: Sometimes things are almost as simple as they seem. Do consider, however, what @whuber recommended about tiny data sets. How are you defining the median if $N$ is even? What if $N=2$?

Comment: IF n =2, one n is in superior bound and one is inferior bound?

Comment: For problem (1), think about what would happen if you chose a value of $h$ that was different from the number you got for $h_{mean}$. Would $E_{in}(h)$ be higher or lower? If it helps, think about the second derivative at $h_{mean}$, not just the first. And for completeness, don't omit the summation signs in your differentiation exercise and specify what you mean when you write $y$ instead of $y_n$.

Comment: Confused.. The second derivative is 1, isnt it?

Comment: So the second derivative is positive. What does that mean about which way your function's value goes when you change $h$ from its value at $h_{mean}$? Try some simple numerical examples with just a few data points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42032/discussion-between-edm-and-scientistgirl).

Comment: Im still confused. I believe this question requires more through explanation or more math experience from my side

Answer (score 2):

You answered (1) well.

As far as (2) goes, note that when $N \ge 3$ and $y_N$ is replaced by $y_N+E$ **and $y_N + E \ge y_{\lfloor (N+1)/2\rfloor}$**,

$$h_{\text{med}}(E) = \frac{1}{2}\left(y_{\lfloor (N+1)/2\rfloor} + y_{\lfloor N/2\rfloor}\right)$$

and

$$h_{\text{mean}}(E) =  \left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{N}y_i\right) + \frac{1}{n}E.$$

Therefore $h_{\text{mean}}$ is a linear function of $E$ with slope $1/N$: in particular, as $E\to\infty$, $h_{\text{mean}}\to \infty$.

However, $h_{\text{med}}$ is *constant*, so as $E\to\infty$, *it remains unchanged.*

The lesson is that when you have more than two data values, $h_{\text{med}}$ is unchanged when the largest of them is arbitrarily increased, but $h_{\text{mean}}$ changes without bound.  The first one--the *median* of the data--is *resistant* to such "outliers" whereas the second--the *mean* of the data--is *sensitive* to outliers.